# UWP Services Toolkit has unresolved dependency on Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Tags: windows-community-toolkit

I am encountering this problem when building an application that is using the Microsoft.Toolkit.UWP.Services component from the UWP Community toolkit:

> Internal compiler error: MCG0023:UnresolvableAssemblyReference Unresolvable assembly reference 'Assembly(Name=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=2.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ContentType=WindowsRuntime)' found. Please check the references in your build system. A reference is either missing or an assembly is missing an expected type.

The Min/Max version of my UWP app is 16299 (Fall Creators Update SDK).

This problem does not reproduce in debug builds.

I did a package-downgrade as suggested by this thread: https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/4768 by installing https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.22.302111727  instead, however this exposes a crash within the 'OneDriveService' component.

Does anyone have a solution to get The services part of the toolkit working in Win 10 16299?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please create an issue in the toolkit repo for better tracking and visibility ?
https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues